# trying to understand how Template Class works

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, template-classes

I have done this assignment as best as i understood it but i am pretty sure there are radical problems. I'll be Looking forward to your comments on how to make it better. The problem definition is as follows:
Two classes.  `XBoxGame` and `WorldPeace`.

Template class called `Gift`.  Has one method called `shake()`.  Inside `shake()`, we are going to call `MakeNoise()` on an instance of our template type `T`.  ONLY `XBoxGame` has `MakeNoise()` as a method.

Now in `main()` as soon as you try to make a "`Gift` that holds an `XBoxGame`" (see what I did there?) you'll know if it works when you compile.  Try to `Gift<WorldPeace>` and it won't compile because `MakeNoise()` is missing.  What you turn in should just have the correctly templated  `XBoxGame` class calling `shake()`, and a `WorldPeace()` that compiles, but only because it is not used in `main()`.

End result "You can only put a class that makes noise in a gift".
The Code i wrote:

```
#include <iostream>   
  class XBoxGame
  {
      void makeNoise(int,int)
    {
      std::cout << "Is this Working ? ";
    };
  };

class WorldPeace
{};


  template <typename T>
   class Gift
   {
     public:
       T shake()
     {
       void XboxGame::makeNoise();
     }
   };
```

The Main:

```
#include "Template.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 Gift <XBoxGame> ;
 Gift <WorldPeace>;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some problems in your code.

In no particular order...

(1) in `Gift::shake()` you call `XboxGame::makeNoise()` but you defined the class with an upper `B` (`XBoxGame`).

(2) in `Gift::shake()` you write

```
void XBoxGame::makeNoise();
```

that is a prototipe for a method, not a call

(3) in `Gift::shake()`, if you remove `void` (see point 2), the following instruction

```
XBoxGame::makeNoise();
```

become the call to a `makeNoise()` *`static`* method in `XBoxGame` `class`; but you defined `makeNoise()` as a not `static` method.

You can define `makeNoise()` as `static` or you can call from an actual `XBoxGame` object; something like

```
  T shake()
   {
     XBoxGame xbg;

     xbg.makeNoise();
   }
```

or even

```
  T shake()
   { XBoxGame().makeNoise(); }
```

(4) you've (implicitly) defined `makeNoise()` as a `private` method of `XBoxGame`. If you want call it in a `Gift` object, you have to declare it as `public` (or define `XBoxGame` as a `struct`, so implicitly declaring `makeNoise()` as `public`

(5) you've defined `makeNoise()`, in `XBoxGame`, as a method that receive a couple of (unused) int values but you call it without arguments; you have to correct this point; a solution can be passing a couple of `int`s calling it; by example

```
  T shake()
   { XBoxGame().makeNoise(0, 0); }
```

(6) in `main()`, le following instructions

```
Gift <XBoxGame>;
Gift <WorldPeace>;
```

are declaring nothing; you should give a couples of names for a cuoples of variables

```
Gift<XBoxGame>    gx;
Gift<WorldPeace>  gv;
```

or transform this in the creation of a couple of temporary objects (avoiding a couples of "unused variable" warnings)

```
Gift<XBoxGame>();
Gift<WorldPeace>();
```

(7) if you want to see the "Is this Working ?" messages, you have to call the `shake()` methods

```
Gift<XBoxGame>().shake();
Gift<WorldPeace>().shake();
```

(8) your shake method is declared as returning `T` but return nothing; this is a problem that you can solve, by example, defining it as a `void` method

```
  void shake()
   { XBoxGame().makeNoise(0, 0); }
```

So, the following code compiles

```
#include <iostream>   

class XBoxGame
 {
   public:
      void makeNoise(int,int)
       { std::cout << "Is this Working ? " << std::endl; };
 };

class WorldPeace
 {};


template <typename T>
class Gift
 {
   public:
      void shake()
       { XBoxGame().makeNoise(0, 0); }
 };

int main()
 {
   Gift<XBoxGame>().shake();
   Gift<WorldPeace>().shake();
 }
```

Hope this helps.

**-- EDIT --**

(9) Not sure to understand but, if you want that only `Gift<XBoxGame>` compile (because only `XBoxGame` implement `makeNoise()`, I suppose you should write `shake()` using the `T` type; so something like

```
  void shake()
   { T().makeNoise(0, 0); }
```

if `makeNoise()` is an ordinary method in `XBoxGame` or

```
  void shake()
   { T::makeNoise(0, 0); }
```

if `makeNoine()` is a `static` method.

Comment: Thank you so much max66. you explained everything perfectly, and i understood all my problems man. Thx